# Can't list metamask accounts using web3py eth.accounts

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, metamask, web3py

I've already installed and created metamask accounts and signed in on my browser chrome. I'm trying to list those accounts following ChatGPT tutorial to connect a HTTPProvider, then call function eth.accounts. However, it didn't work at all.

I'm so new to web3. I'm even don't wth is the HTTPProvider. Someone please help me out?

```
from web3 import Web3
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/31a0a5e5d6684eafac834de74e9d2c06'))
print(web3.is_connected())
print(web3.eth.accounts)
```

Explain what is a HTTPProvider in an unstandable way.
Tell me why my code didn't work, and suggest what I should do?

Comment: What does "it didn't work at all" mean exactly? What happened?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Web3.py cannot access accounts on MetaMask. Only JavaScript frontend can.

[Please read Web3.py documentation on how to import private keys to your Python application](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html). You should not use `web3.eth.accounts` in the first place, but local accounts with imported private keys with you are working with Python code. Your Python process is not going to connect to your MetaMask in any way.

Whatever is "ChatGPT tutorial" is likely nonsense, so please forget whatever you have read in ChatGPT and read the project documentation.